# Spring HTML - No consigo mostrar la imagen, la primera vez que subo la imagen

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

estoy realizando una aplicación en Spring con Java, y estoy teniendo el siguiente problema para visualizar la imagen que quiero mostrar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero remarcar que este error solo me aparece, si la pelicula que he subido ha sido durante ese momento en el que tengo lanzada la aplicación. Si después de este error, reinicio mi aplicación la vuelvo a lanzar, y realizo la búsqueda, entonces si que me aparecen las imagen correctamente.

**Controlador**

```
    @GetMapping("/searched-film/{title}")
public String searchedFilm(@PathVariable String title, Model model) {

    List<Film> listFilm = filmService.searchFilmsByTitle(title);

    model.addAttribute("films", listFilm);

    return "searched-film";
}
```

**Service**

public class FilmServiceImpl implements FilmService {

```
@Autowired
FilmRepository filmRepository;

@Override
public Boolean saveFilm(Film film, User user) {

    film.setMigrate(false);
    film.setUser(user);

    try {
        log.info("Saving de film in the database");
        filmRepository.save(film);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Error save the film in the database");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public List<Film> searchFilmsByTitle(String title) {
    List<Film> listFilmByTitle = filmRepository.searchFilmsByTitleContaining(title);
    return listFilmByTitle;
}
```

**Searched-film.html**

```
<h3>Resultados de la busqueda</h3>
<hr>
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" th:each="film : ${films}">
            <div th:value="${film.id}" class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" th:src="${film.poster}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${film.title}">Card title</h5>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ver película</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por si acaso, voy también a dejar el código que maneja la subida de peliculas por si hubiera algún error:

**Controller**

```
  @PostMapping("/new-film")
ModelAndView newFilm(@ModelAttribute("film") Film film, @RequestParam("cartel") MultipartFile archive, ModelAndView modelAndView, Model model) {

    UserDetails userDetailsAuthenticate = SecurityConfig.getAuthenticatedUserDetails();

    User user = userService.findUserByUsername(userDetailsAuthenticate.getUsername());

    film = filmImageService.saveImage(archive, film);

    filmService.saveFilm(film, user);

    List<Person> listPerson = personService.allPerson();

    model.addAttribute("director", listPerson.stream().filter(person -> person.getType().equals(TypePersonEnum.DIRECTOR)));
    model.addAttribute("musician", listPerson.stream().filter(person -> person.getType().equals(TypePersonEnum.MUSICO)));
    model.addAttribute("screenwriter", listPerson.stream().filter(person -> person.getType().equals(TypePersonEnum.GUIONISTA)));
    model.addAttribute("photographer", listPerson.stream().filter(person -> person.getType().equals(TypePersonEnum.FOTOGRAFO)));
    model.addAttribute("actor", listPerson.stream().filter(person -> person.getType().equals(TypePersonEnum.ACTOR)));

    modelAndView.addObject("newFilmSuccesfull", "Se ha creado la película");

    modelAndView.setViewName("new-film");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**Service - Subida de la imagen a mi local**

```
public class FilmImageServiceImpl implements FilmImageService {

@Override
public Film saveImage(MultipartFile archive, Film film) {

    try {
        Path pathFinal = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/images/cover page/" + archive.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(pathFinal, archive.getBytes());
        film.setPoster(pathFinal.toString().substring(25));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se ha introducido ninguna imagen. Vuelva a intentarlo");
    }

    return film;
}
```

}

**Service-Almacenar la pelicula**

```
@Autowired
FilmRepository filmRepository;

@Override
public Boolean saveFilm(Film film, User user) {

    film.setMigrate(false);
    film.setUser(user);

    try {
        log.info("Saving de film in the database");
        filmRepository.save(film);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Error save the film in the database");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```